# What does "Function.call.bind(Function.bind)" mean?

Tags: javascript

I need your help. I got stuck with these code lines

```
var bind = Function.call.bind(Function.bind);
bind(CC, Components);
```

I try to understand what they are and how they work but I cannot :-(

1. Could someone help to explain clearly how they works? As I
   understand, "Function.call.bind" will invoke a function which is
   bind to it via bind(). And "Function.bind" will return a function
   which is called by "Function.call.bind". Also not sure how "bind(CC,
   Components)" works. Looks like Components will be bind to CC. Please
   correct me if I am wrong.
2. In case I don't want to use Function constructor like that, what should I do to re-write the code above in another way but still keeps the same workflow/logic?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## 1. What is `Function#bind` and standalone `bind` function?

### `Function#bind`

A call to `Function#bind` creates a new function that is eternally bound to the context passed as the first argument. `Function#bind` operates as a *method on a function*. That is, you can only bind the function that `Function#bind` is invoked on.

```
let str = 'Hello, World!'
let fn = () => console.log(this)

// Bind the `this` to be `str`
let boundFn = fn.bind(str)
boundFn() // => 'Hello, World!'

// Attempt re-bind:
boundFn = fn.bind('new str')
boundFn() // => 'Hello, World!'
```

______

### `Function#call`

`Function#call` is different to `Function#bind` in that it **executes** the given function with a context and any other arguments given. It does not return a new bound function.

```
let str = 'Hello, '
let fn = (who) => console.log(this + who)
fn.call(str, 'World!') // => 'Hello, World!'
```

______

### Passing a function by reference loses its context

When we pass a function by reference we lose its context. In this case, it means we cannot simply do `var bind = Function.bind` and call `bind` as a standalone function.

```
let log = () => console.log('Hello, World!')
let bind = Function.bind;    
bind(log) // => Uncaught TypeError: Bind must be called on a function
```

______

### Creating a standalone function `bind`

The code that you shared creates a shorthand (standalone) function that is equivalent to `Function#bind` but accepts the function to bind as its first argument and the context to bind that function to as its second, rather than invoking the `bind` method as a member of the function that is being bound (e.g. `fn.bind(ctx)`).

```
// Create standalone `bind` function
let bind = Function.call.bind(Function.bind);

let obj = { hello: 'World!' }
let log = () => console.log(this)
let boundFn = bind(log, obj)
boundFn() // => { hello: 'World!' }
```

______

## 2. How to achieve this functionality without `Function#bind`?

The above solution accepts a function and a second argument that defines the returned function's context (`this`). We can imitate this functionality quite simply with a helper function that accepts the same type of arguments and returns a function that when invoked executes the function with the given context and arguments using `Function#call`.

1. The function to bind
2. The context to bind the function to

For example:

```
function bind (fn, ctx) {
    return function (...args) {
        fn.call(ctx, ...args);
    };
}
```

Note that this isn't quite the same as creating a bound function. You can [read about what happens during the creation of a bound function in `9.4.1.3 BoundFunctionCreate` in the spec](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-boundfunctioncreate).

Comment: And your `boundFn` will only return `'World!'`

Comment: A great and detailed explanation, thank you! One question: what is the practical application of a standalone `bind` function?

Comment: "How to achieve this functionality without `Function#bind` - to be fair there is a bunch of things `.bind` does that your code there doesn't do.

Comment: @Mathletics - Thanks again!

Comment: Thanks @sdgluck and all for your detailed explanation and discussion. They help me so much. You are genius.

Answer (score 3):

1. The context of a function is determined by how it is called, so in order for the shorthand `bind` to work correctly, you must generate a function where `this` is `Function.bind`. Note the signature of `call`:

   ```
   .call(thisArg[, arg1[, arg2[, ...]]])
   ```

   So this execution returns a function bound to `Function.bind`. In your specific case, it will bind `CC` to `Components`, so that when you invoke `CC()`, the context (`this`) will be `Components`.
2. Per @BenjaminGruenbaum you can do `let bind = (fn, ...args) => fn.bind(...args);`

Comment: Sure there is another way `let bind = (fn, ...args) => fn.bind(...args);`

Comment: I still don't understand how `bind` is supposed to be used and what the difference is between this `bind` and the native `bind`.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum morning coffee seems to have worn off; yes, obviously that is not using the context. Thanks again.

Comment: @DmytroShevchenko with this, you can write `bind(fn, ...args)` instead of `fn.bind(...args)`. I don't see the value beyond stylistic preference, but maybe someone else can enlighten us both.