# Is there a Javascript depipe method? like bind or call but for unpiping a piped prototype

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-class

Is there an official way to pass the head of a pipe function as a normal function argument? Like how you can modify functions with `.call` and `.bind`, I want to modify String.prototype.includes so that it looks like `includes('a')('acd')`. Basically, I want a function that makes it's first argument, say 'abc', the String instance in `String.prototype.includes('a')`

He'res my best attempt... that doesn't work, because, why would it
`['abc'].some(String.prototype.includes('b'))`

Basically I want a cool confusing version of this
`x => x.includes('b')`

Is there a version of call, bind or depipe method in Javascript that does what I need?

Related: [What does "Function.call.bind(Function.bind)" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33217983/what-does-function-call-bindfunction-bind-mean)

Comment: Do you mean overriding the built-in prototype method?

Comment: "*a cool confusing version*" so...`['abc'].some(flip(Function.prototype.call.bind(String.prototype.includes))("b"))` where `flip = f => a => b => f(b, a)`? Or is that more confusing than cool? https://jsbin.com/bakoyip/edit?js,console

Comment: @ISAE no because `String.prototype.includes('a')` returns a boolean, not a function. `String.includes('a')` and `String.includes('a').prototype` are also not functions... `Function.bind` returns a function, `Function.prototype` returns an object. I'm looking for a `Function.bind` that instead of taking context as argument, takes a value like a String.

Comment: @VLAZ OMG... are you passing string values as the this context in `Function.protoype.call()` ... I think that's it 

Comment: @RayFoss it's ugly as sin and I wouldn't actually recommend it. But it's possible to do, yes. It's probably more easy on the eyes if you just have something like `callMethod = m => y => x => x[m](y)` which will allow you to derive `has = callMethod("includes")` and then do `["abc"].some(has("b"))`. Not sure if that's what you're looking for. https://jsbin.com/rokucik/1/edit?js,console

Comment: it is... Ill use `myArray.some(hay => String.prototype.includes.call(hay, '.'))` to detect if an array of strings has strings with dots... which are dangerous in my context. codesandbox.io/s/de-currying-example-vju5z?file=/src/index.js I've never fully thought of strings as objects, or a valid context. The word I was looking for is de-currying. This explains so much... like why the context of stream events is not a child of where you instantiated the stream.

Comment: @RayFoss not really sure how that's better than `x => x.includes(".")`. You can generalise it to `includes = y => x => x.includes(y)` and use `arr.some(includes("."))` if you want to have it reusable. So, you'd even be able to do `isDangerous = includes(".")` and then `arr.some(isDangerous)` if you want self-documenting code.

Comment: @VLAZ it's not. But it hides a lot of whats happening, it hides what Javascript is to the point where you could go decades without understanding prototypical inheritance and lexical scoping. I'll leave that in as a reminder of our origins in a world of strict linting, classes and modules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built-in way to do this. Ignoring libraries like ramda/lodash.fp that let you do this through helper methods - you would need to implement your own helper. As the arguments are "reversed" you cannot simply eta-reduce (avoid the extra lambda):

```js
// all these functions exist in Ramda
function makeThisAnArgument(fn) { // uncurry this
  return (arg, ...args) => fn.call(arg, ...args)
}
function reverseArguments(fn) {
  return (...args) => fn.call(null, ...args.reverse());
}
// this would let you easily do:
const reversed = reverseArguments(makeThisAnArgument(String.prototype.includes))
const includesA = reversed.bind(null, 'a');
includesA('abc'); // true
includesA('bc'); // false
```

In general, consider seeing the great talk about Ramda [Hey Underscore, You're doing it Wrong!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m3svKOdZijA) that explains the call order, convention and method signatures needed to enable a composable API like the one you're asking for which is the one Ramda exposes.

Comment: You _can_ of course one-liner it, but please don't :D

Answer (score 1):

So as far as i understand you need a `curry` utility function that will convert a multiple argument function into a partially applicable one. Like;

```
var curry = f => f.length ? (...a) => curry(f.bind(f,...a)) : f(),
```

Now the `String.prototype.includes()` normally takes the `this` argument in the `includes` function direcly from the calling object. However we can still enforce JS to manifest `includes` as a dual argument function like `(x,t) => String.prototype.includes.call(t,x)` where `t` is the `this` and `x` is the existing argument.

Now with these tools at hand we can go ahead and implement your functionality.

```js
var curry = f => f.length ? (...a) => curry(f.bind(f,...a)) : f(),
    incl  = curry((x,t) => String.prototype.includes.call(t,x));
console.log(incl("llo")("Hello World..!"));
console.log(incl("g")("abcdefg"));
console.log(incl("i")("abcdefg"));
```